# ASP:UpdatePanel - Add JavaScript on Button Click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a `asp:UpdatePanel` with a `asp:Button` and a `asp:TextBox`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Click" ID="button" onclick="button_Click"/>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" Title="Text" ID="text" Style="margin-top: 50px;" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the `button_Click` method is:

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    text.Attributes.Add("title", "Box");
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(ScriptManager), "Tooltify", "tooltipfy();", true);
}
```

`tooltify()` is a javascript function.

```
var tooltipfy = function () {
    alert('');
    $('[title]').qtip({
        style: {
            tip: {
                corner: true,
                width: 10,
                height: 5
            },
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-rounded ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-tipsy'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'bottom left',
            at: 'top right',
            adjust: {
                x: -10,
                y: 0
            }
        },
        events: {
            show: function (event, api) {
                $('.ui-tooltip-content').addClass('ui-tooltip-center');
            }
        },
        show: {
            effect: function (offset) {
                $(this).show("slide", { direction: "up" }, 500);
            }
        },
        hide: {
            effect: function (offset) {
                $(this).hide("explode", 500);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is the function is not executing.

How can I call JavaScript function while using `asp:UpdatePanel`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `ScriptManger` when using `UpdatePanel`.

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),"Tooltify", "tooltipfy();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not in the possibility to test it now, but according to [this blog](http://www.storm-consultancy.com/blog/development/code-snippets/execute-javascript-when-an-updatepanel-is-updated/) you should get it to work with `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript`.

Comment: using ScriptManager, not ClientScript

Comment: Thank you. Using `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` it is working.

Answer (score 0):

using `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` is not good practice.
If your Javascript function (tooltipfy) should update some controls, you should place these controls under your `asp:UpdatePanel`  and update them in your code behind like this:

```
someDiv.Style.Add("display", "inline");
someDiv.InnerHtml = Text;
otherControl.Style.Add("display", "block");
```